# Resizing html canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, resize, html5-canvas

I'm trying to smoothly resize an html5 canvas element.  I've cobbled together bits of code and I think the following should work:

```
<body>
    <header id='myheader' height='200'>
        <canvas id='mycanvas' width='200' height='200'></canvas>

        <script>

        var mycanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
        var context = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
        var centerX = mycanvas.width / 2;
        var centerY = mycanvas.height / 2;
        var radius = 70;

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = 'blue';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        context.stroke();

        var animate = function(prop, val, duration) {
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var end = start + duration;
            var current = mycanvas[prop];
            var distance = val - current;
            var step = function() {
                var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                var progress = Math.min((duration - (end - timestamp)) / duration, 1);
                mycanvas[prop] = current + (distance * progress);
                if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(step);
            };
            return step();
        };

        animate('mycanvas.height', 10, 1000);

        </script>
    </header>       
</body>
```

...but obviously it doesn't!  The result I'm looking for is a canvas that shrinks to just show the middle part of the circle (something more interesting than a circle will be added later).  Is there anything obvious that I'm missing, or am I just doing this the wrong way?  Ultimately I want to to resize both the canvas and the header together, so getting the canvas resizing to work is stage 1.  Any help appreciated...

(Edit: actually, I ultimately want to resize both the canvas and header in response to a scroll event - which I think means avoiding a css solution - but I want to get this bit working first!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few changes to your script that I believe do what you want:

```
    var mycanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    var context = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
    var radius = 70;

    function draw() {
        var centerX = mycanvas.width / 2;
        var centerY = mycanvas.height / 2;

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = 'blue';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        context.stroke();
    }

    var animate = function(target, prop, val, duration, action) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        var end = start + duration;
        var current = target[prop];
        var distance = val - current;
        var step = function() {
            var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
            var progress = Math.min((duration - (end - timestamp)) / duration, 1);
            target[prop] = current + (distance * progress);
            action();
            if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(step);
        };
        return step();
    };

    animate(mycanvas, 'height', 10, 1000, draw);
```

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I wanted it to do - massively helpful.